# How kernel provides services to other parts of operating system?

Tags: operating-system, kernel

I went through the definitions of kernel on internet and i saw  in many definitions that kernel provides services to other parts of OS.
What do they mean by kernel provides services to other parts of OS.
Can anyone explain with some valid example.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(operating_system)#System_calls

Comment: You didnt get my question. I want to know what are those other parts of OS and how kernel provides services to these parts.

Comment: 'what are those other parts of OS' is not what you asked.  This question is anyway WAY too broad and asking for examples is off-topic;(

Comment: The explanation of kernel is way too broad on internet that is why i asked the question here @Martin James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> kernel provides services to other parts of OS.

By "others" they mean parts of OS which works in *user space* (non-priveledged code). Among them are:

- Libraries, provided by OS and used by 3d party applications (or 3d-party libraries).
- Frameworks, e.g. one provided windows subsystem.
- Applications (executables) provided by OS itself. E.g. `cd` command.

If any of those component needs a help from the kernel, it uses one of the kernel's service. Usually, kernel's service is provided via syscall mechanism.